# React.js: Can certain components be made SSR-rendering only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

Coming from some classic server-side template languages (php, jsp), I have a general architectural question on React.js:

**Can I limit certain components of a page to be rendered server-side only? And reduce the client-side javascript bundle accordingly?**

*I find that often ridiculously large. One reason (afaik): Every component must have the capability to be re-rendered on state changes and SPA-(aka soft, virtual..) page navigation, since all changes come in as data, not as prerendered html chunks (afaik).

[image]

**Basically, I see 2 different types of content sections in almost all of my web projects:**

**1) highly dynamic “facebook-ish” interactive sections**
Personal greetings, messages and message counters, likes and replies… here default React behavior is at its best: new data comes in, global state (redux store) changes and all affected components get re-rendered. Which would be a daunting task without react and redux sound principles. And certainly client-side rendering/updates are the way to go.

That's often the user-login area at top ("Hello Joe, 5 unread messages"), some live data (stock, weather,…) in the middle and said comments closer to the bottom.

**2) SSR “static” content** (think PHP)

However, for many sections I know for sure, *nothing* is client-side dynamic. Footer Menus for example, might stem from a database, but are certain to not change for the duration of the session. (Even if John Doe decides to like, comment or change his name…)

Rendering them only server-side would be enough. Often the main content block can also do with SSR-only. (And all the layout-ish sub-components needed to render its html)

Still, I have to give all components to the client bundle, so that also virtual/soft page navigation works... (which transmits new data, but not pre-rendered sections)

---

*You could tell me as a workaround to simply keep the footer out of the react container mounting point, but that's not my point... "static" aka sections that can do with pure SSR might be elsewhere, too, between dynamic header and lower response/feedback/liking sections…*

---

I would like to mark Type-2-components as "SSR-is-enough" (and also their sub-components – unless webpack dependency tree figures out, they are used in Type1-CSR-components, too…).

So send it as a single html blob. Also receiving it "pre-rendered" on SPA-ish virtual page navigation would be needed afaik. (since the component knowledge will be missing from the client bundle)

**Is there a way to do this? Has someone thought of this general, imho common problem before...?**

Comment: Hi Frank, Did you find some workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hydrating only certain components is definitely a problem that is being thought about.

One web framework that solves is problem is [Astro](https://astro.build/). It only hydrates components which are actually interactive.

Another is [Fresh](https://fresh.deno.dev/), which has a concept called "islands." The entire page is server-side generated and when you need interactivity, you create an "island" which is a component which is hydrated on the client.